# Getting error "Undefined control sequence" for \acmBookTitle

Tags: errors, overleaf, undefined, compilation-error

I'm using Overleaf and I used the ACM template provided for submission to a conference. It's my first time with LaTeX and with OverLeaf.

I'm getting an error "Undefined control sequence" for the following line.

```
\acmBooktitle{ICSE '18 Companion: 40th International Conference on
Software Engineering Companion, May 27-June 3, 2018, Gothenburg,
Sweden}
```

I thought I'd check the log file to get more info. But this is all I got.

```
./Main.tex:110: Undefined control sequence. l.110 \acmBooktitle
                    {ICSE '18 Companion: 40th International Conference on So...
```

Need urgent help. Thanks

Comment: If you use one of the ACM templates in the Overleaf Gallery here: https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/acm The `\acmBooktitle` command should be available. Choose the template you need from that page, and then click on "Open as Template".

Comment: I used the ACM Template from Overleaf and it was fine. I copy-pasted the ACM copyright code I received from the conference and I've been getting this error since I did that.

Answer (score 8):

There is an outdated and now incorrect statement in Masud's answer: "it seems to me `\acmBooktitle` part is optional."

The ACM conferences now have an automated checking system called TAPS for checking your LaTeX code.  That's right, they will request your actual source files now.  TAPS will throw errors and reject your upload if you are missing `\acmBooktitle`.  Error text: "Required commands for metadata missing (`\acmBooktitle` )".  It also throws errors if your LaTeX code redefined the `\baselinestretch` command to get a few extra lines squeezed into your paper.  They seem to be banning practices that authors previously got away with.

I, too, got an undefined control sequence error from using the `\acmBookTitle` line from the provided ACM copyright code with the new ACM template provided on Overleaf.  It would probably be best to contact support through the interface TAPS provides, but for now my advisor suggests the following workaround code:

```
\def\acmBooktitle#1{\gdef\@acmBooktitle{#1}}
\acmBooktitle{Proceedings of \acmConference@name
       \ifx\acmConference@name\acmConference@shortname\else
         \ (\acmConference@shortname)\fi}
```

Make sure you follow their advice to insert the ACM boilerplate section between `\begin{document}` and `\maketitle`; the Overleaf template might default to somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

I got the similar error with the ACM provided copyright Latex code. I tried commenting out `\acmBooktitle` and it worked for me. I checked ACM provided [template](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) and [sigconf sample](https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/blob/master/sample-sigconf.tex#L33) and it seems to me  `\acmBooktitle` part is optional.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if your acmart.cls contains the definition of `\def\acmBooktitle`. The acmart.cls file should have the same content of the file available on http://www.sigplan.org/sites/default/files/acmart/current/acmart.cls.

Comment: Thank you, after adding this file into the source folder, the file compiles successfully.